# Tomcat -- Running a web application

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm trying to run a sample app in Tomcat. I've installed tomcat, set up the environment variable by creating a new system variable called JAVA_HOME which is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20. And I've created a new dir for the web app in the tomcat program directory. In the cmd prompt I navigate  to the tomcat program directory and type in bin/startup.sh and I get the following error: 'bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.
I'm using tomcat 6.0 and I'm on a windows machine. What could the problem?

Comment: If this is your first time installing Tomcat, and you're running Windows, it would probably be easier to simply download the Tomcat Windows Service Installer (from the bottom of [this page](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi) ) and use that.  Then to start or stop Tomcat, simply use the Services control panel in Windows (it's located under Administrative Tools).

Comment: related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19559371/tomcat-startup-bat-is-missing

Comment: it should be bin\startup.bat  - startup.sh is used in linux based shells.  The startup.bat should work, but it's recommended that you use "bin\catalina.bat start" instead.  You need environment variables CATALINA_BASE and CATALINA_HOME set before doing this.  Set both to the directory where you've got tomcat installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try typing in `bin\startup.bat` on a Windows machine and still get the same error, there's a possibility that Windows is not seeing the batch script where it should be. As [a-horse-with-no-name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501012/tomcat-running-a-web-application/4501036#4501036) already said, try installing Tomcat to a location where there are no spaces in the path. In your case, anywhere other than `Program Files`.

EDIT: To resolve this space issue, you can do two things: 1) Install JDK/JRE to a common location without spaces (say, C:\Java) and set it to be JAVA_HOME environment variable. 2) Install Tomcat to another location (say, C:\Tomcat) and proceed from there. Since these are all in common location, I believe you can do this as a limited account user without needing admin privileges.

Comment: Alright. Also when i click on monitor or configure tomcat i get the following error: access is denied. Unable to open the service 'Tomcat6'

Comment: Krysten, it looks like you installed Tomcat as an administrator on your machine (Consequently, installed it to `Program Files`). Try installing as a normal user (limited account) and fire it up.

Comment: Ok and when it says select a path of a J2SE 5.0 or later JRE installed on your system (I have a 64 bit) is this the correct path      C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6?

Comment: Can you locate your java executable there? If so, that's the right path. I wouldn't usually recommend setting JAVA_HOME to `C:\Program Files` or any location with spaces, for that matter. Anyway, just be aware that Windows can throw path file issues where there are spaces in pathnames.

Comment: is there an alternative to tomcat that would allow me to avoid this problem

Answer (score 3):

On Windows you must run the `startup.bat` file instead of the `startup.sh` file (note the extension is different).

Also, enter the `bin` directory before executing the bat script.

```
cd bin 
startup.bat
```

Comment: How can you get the same `bin` error if you're command doesn't include the `bin` command?

Comment: Sorry that was before your edit and now I get this error: startup.bat is not recognized as an internal or external command..

Answer (score 1):

Your on windows try:

```
bin\startup.bat
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Tomcat (and possibly the JDK) into a directory without spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The script you ran is intended for *nix systems.  Try `bin\startup.bat`

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by some of the answers. First, the error you are receiving is from Windows. Nothing to do with Tomcat. The Windows OS thinks you have entered a command, and doesn't recognize it. Files with the .bat extension are always recognized by Windows as Batch file commands....... soooo..... Navigate to the bin directory, again, under your tomcat installation. Then....

Don't append the bin in front of the command. You should do a quick look to make sure that the "startup.bat" file is here (dir *.bat). Then just type "startup.bat".

Seems like I just type "catalina.bat start" (for my tomcat catalina installation)