# Tomcat: startup.bat is missing

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, batch-file

In many materials about tomcat what I've looked I saw that authors uses exeternal batch script for start and stop tomcat.

I didn't see information about wrting this script. I think this script provided by tomcat.

I used exe file for installing my tomcat 7 on my windows 7. In tomcat directory I search startup.bat. This file is missed.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be in the `/bin` directory. If you're missing this file possibly it means that you have installed Tomcat using Windows Installer. Try to [download](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi) appropriate .zip archive, I believe that you will find startup script there.

Answer (score 5):

I was puzzled by this - windows people need to script too!

However I think it is because tomcat gets installed as a service with a manager.  If you want to start and stop it without using the manager you start and stop the service directly.

You can do this by typing (in an admin command prompt)

```
net start tomcat7
```

and

```
net stop tomcat7
```

Comment: this answer is beautiful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Though it would be everywhere, still if you download the zip from their site, you can follow these instructions - http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Tomcat_HowTo.html

bin\startup.bat is for windows & .sh is for Unix.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked `bin` directory under Tomcat instalation dir? It should containt *.bat for start and stop server etc.

Comment: I searched in all directories deeper that catalina_home

Comment: Did you mean that you checked/looked/searched in every directory?

Comment: And there is nothing there? No bin directory? Than your installation is either corrupted or not compleate.

Comment: I have bin directory but there are any jar and any exe files

Comment: I wrote you to look for BAT files, not exe nor jar

Comment: these files are missed

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start Tomcat server by using startup.bat and you are unable to find it(that's because installer does not have it, you can only see it if you download and run .zip this will show startup.bat explicitly https://www.screencast.com/t/RMPCq5eJre3), 
So to solve the issue just go to C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0_Tomcat7\bin and double click Tomcat.exe, a command prompt like screen will appear this is the the same as clicking startup.bat script. Hope this helps